# $.ajax() priority

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the next js function that is working good:

```
$(function () {
    $(".country").click(function () {
        var countries = Array();
        $(".country:checked:enabled").each(function(i, element){
            countries[i] =  $(element).attr("id");
        });
        countries_string = countries.join(",");            
        $('#scroll').scrollTop(0);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckBoxCountryFilter", "CheckBox")',
            data: {countries:countries_string},
            success: function (result) {
                //console.log(result);
                $("#wineResult").html(result);
            }             
        });
        if(countries.length > 0){
            $("#countryImage").html('<img src="/Content/Images/icons/check.png">');            
        }else{
            $("#countryImage").html('');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ArtikelNumber", "CheckBox")',
            type: 'POST',                
            success: function (result) {
                $("#artikelNumber").html(result);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

but there are one problem the first $.ajax() is not executing sometime first, can I do somthing that the fist $.ajax() ever time execut first?? thank you

Comment: Call the second `.ajax()` in the callback of the first.

Comment: That's sort of the point of the ajax calls in the first place.  You may not know exactly how long it'll take to return, so your browser can do other things.  In this case that other thing is another ajax call.  As the answerers suggest, if sequence is important, put the second call in the callback of the first call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force that by moving the second `$.ajax` call into the `success` of the first one

```
$(function () {
    $(".country").click(function () {
        var countries = Array();
        $(".country:checked:enabled").each(function(i, element){
            countries[i] =  $(element).attr("id");
        });
        countries_string = countries.join(",");            
        $('#scroll').scrollTop(0);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckBoxCountryFilter", "CheckBox")',
            data: {countries:countries_string},
            success: function (result) {
                //console.log(result);
                $("#wineResult").html(result);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ArtikelNumber", "CheckBox")',
                    type: 'POST',                
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#artikelNumber").html(result);
                    }
                }); 
            }             
        });
        if(countries.length > 0){
            $("#countryImage").html('<img src="/Content/Images/icons/check.png">');            
        }else{
            $("#countryImage").html('');
        }
    });
});
```